# programming language independent random number generator

Tags: language-agnostic, random, cross-platform

Does it exist a programming platform / language independent random number generator?
A family of libraries that given a seed will return the very same sequence of (obviously pseudo-)random numbers, and that exist for the most used programming languages / platforms (at least C, JMV, CLI, php, python) and guarantee for platform compatibility (win/linux/mac/android)

I know I can implement a well known algorithm myself for all, but we all do know that writing a random number gen. is DIFFICULT, so a bullet-proof implementation could be a nice thing to have.

Comment: Can you provide a reason for language independent random number generator? I am having difficulty understanding your use case.

Comment: I'm thinking about creating a protocol to play card game online. Since it is a protocol, it should be platform agnostic and programming language agnostic. It is going to be very broad on scope (permits not only poker, but also [CCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectible_card_game)) and so cryptography and strong random generator is a must. The idea is that both client instantiate a seed to let the random events in the game, but when the game is finished the must share their local seed with other parties to see if they cheadted.

Comment: @Wishper: How will you prevent people from lying about their local seed?

Comment: @Marcin the protocol was studied in a way that made be very difficult to brute-force a seed in order to 'let the die throw wanted result' However I'll study mental poker before asking more question

Comment: @Wishper: I'm no expert on random number generation, but consider whether it is feasible to update the seed on every "throw" using something other than brute-force.

Comment: @Marcin What was I thinking about was something like: there are 2 players, Anna and Bob. When Anna want to 'make a roll', she declares that. Bob reply with a newly created random seed X. Anna builds a new number generator doing Anna's private seed XOR X, and extract the first number from it. Anna cannot prepare a 'good seed' before the game to extract all high numbers (I'm simplifying), because she cannot foresee seed X. Bob cannot give 'faked' seeds because

Comment: @Wishper: That seems reasonable. Given your use-case, rather than specifying a single library, you would be better off specifying a specific algorithm, and providing a reference implementation in an appropriately portable language.

Comment: @Marcin This is my view: there are 2 players, A and B. When A want to 'make a roll', she declares that. B reply with a newly created random seed X. A builds a new number generator using (A private seed XOR X), and get from it the value. A cannot prepare a 'cheating seed' before the game , because she cannot foresee seed X. B cannot give 'faked' seeds because
1) He does not know A's private seed
2) A can verify B generated seeds because they depend on his private seed
After game players exchange private seeds and verify all steps in the game, can be done if the generator is as in QUESTION TITLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a C library you like. Use the FFI facilities of any other language to access it. Job done.

Update: If you are trying to design a distributed poker system, an identical library is not going to get the job done. Instead, read about the well-studied area of mental poker: http://www.google.co.uk/?q=mental+poker

Comment: Not an expert of StackOverflow: I dont'know if I should +1 your answer or not, since it does not satisfy my question (I'd like a 'pure' implementation, and I'm also not sure that any C lib would behave the same in different architectures) but you resolved my problem (Ie. reinventing the wheel because I was not able to discover the "mental poker" concept that resolves my problem :)

Problem resolved, cannot vote because not enough reputation. :(